# Inner join not working.. shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in

Tags: php, mysql, join, syntax

I am writing an Inner Join to get data from two related tables:

table 1: user

table 2: search_queries.

> I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in .... on
>   line 137

Here is the inner Join I am writing on like 137:

```
ssql = SELECT fname,sname FROM user INNER JOIN search_queries ON(user.id = search_queries.id);
```

Kindly help and let know where I might be getting it wrong.

Comment: `ssql = "SELECT fname,sname FROM user INNER JOIN search_queries WHERE user.id = search_queries.id";`OR `ssql = "SELECT fname,sname FROM user INNER JOIN search_queries ON user.id = search_queries.id";`

Answer (score 3):

This is a PHP error. Put SQL string in quotes:

```
$sql = "SELECT fname, sname FROM user INNER JOIN search_queries ON user.id = search_queries.id";
```

Answer (score 2):

Its look like php error so you need to do like below:-

```
$ssql = "SELECT fname,sname FROM `user` INNER JOIN search_queries WHERE user.id = search_queries.id";
```

OR

```
$ssql = "SELECT fname,sname FROM `user` INNER JOIN search_queries ON user.id = search_queries.id";
```

OR `()` will ok also:-

```
 $ssql = "SELECT fname,sname FROM `user` INNER JOIN search_queries ON (user.id = search_queries.id)";
```

Comment: this will also work (ON user.id = search_queries.id)

Comment: any way this is nice approach.

Answer (score -2):

Remove brackets :

```
SELECT fname,sname 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN search_queries ON user.id = search_queries.id ;
```

Comment: think tank remove your answer, because may be you will face some more -ve marking for this, you can add another answer by writing things correctly. Its just a suggestion for your betterment.